# Python tkinter GUI scale for unit-accurate printing

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, scale

I created a small python program, which places circles in a tkinter gui, like this:

[image: Picture of my GUI]

After the user created the circles, we'll have to print this coordinate system with the circles to a paper, and the whole coordinate system sizes must be accurate for the displayed lengths. I mean, for example one step on the Y axis (which is 10mm in the GUI) must be really 10mm on the printed paper. If a user places a circle with a 5mm diameter, on the printed paper he must measure 5mm as a result. So the real question is, how can I design a Tkinter GUI with pixels etc.., which is real-world accurate after printing it to a simple paper. I've heard about this DPI scale thing, but every computer can have different values, so what is the secure solution for this? Is there any way to use millimeter, or centimeter units during the GUI design procedure?

Thanks for the help!
Ben

I tried scaling pixel values used by tkinter somehow, but without success.

Comment: How were you planning to actually print the contents of your GUI?  Tkinter has no built-in support for that, so this will necessarily involve other software, that's likely to have its own scaling that may or may not be within your control.

Comment: Well maybe some PDF generator tool? But we can talk about the task itself, how to create a program, which places circles in a coordinate system with real world units, which has the same siza after printing it to pdf, then on paper.. etc